# I am trying to display content input field via using select option on the remark table section

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Select Option Show / Hide</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue){
                $(".accept").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();
            } else{
                $(".accept").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});

  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
  <tr>
                   <td width="4%" align="center">Sr. No</td>
                   <td width="15%" align="center">Step Name</td>
                   <td width="7%" align="center">Decision</td>
                   <td width="15%" align="center">Remark</td>
                   
                   
                  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">1.</td>

      <td align="center">Maker
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <div>
          <select>
            <option value="reject">Reject</option>
            <option value="approve">Approve</option>

          </select>
        </div>
      </td>

      <!--<td align="center">ProcessFlow</td>-->

      <td align="center">
   <div>Your Detail is Rejected</div>
        <div class="reject accept"><input type="text" placeholder="This is Rejected"></div>

        <div class="approve accept"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Remark"></div>

      </td>

    </tr>
  </table>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Default text will be required to appear on the Remark column and the input field will be shown once the Approve or Reject select option gets selected. Hence till the remark will appear as it is. Also need once the input field is updated then it shown as in label format. Requesting your help on the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: instead of input do you want to show label by default?

Comment: this is decision feild and if it is get rejected then the user can put remark on the remark columan after selected reject or approve. so i need to show editable first after then updated the remark will get to show its updated. and also the default text will get overwried it.

Comment: please any suggestion on this.

Comment: If I choose reject and enter details in text box, then it has to update the label. Is this your final requirement.

Comment: yes! i want the same way but the label will appear on the same remark columan.